# Select doesn't work after clone element

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, select, jquery-chosen

I use chosen-select (I tried bootstrap-select, select2) to add a search box in my select input. That worked for my first input. However, I have a problem after cloning this form input. In fact, I am able to use the search box with the added select input.

Link to example: http://maxtest.freeserver.me/index3.php#

Could you please help me to fix this?

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Update : Thank you for your reply^^.

I have modify the code, I have removed the id but i am still not able to access to my second input. Why do  you means by my "chosen-select can be bounded to original select", how could i fix that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I Clone Chosen Plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17902507/how-can-i-clone-chosen-plugin) or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523395/how-to-add-chosen-plugin-to-dynamically-created-cloned-css-div?lq=1 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14181884/how-to-clone-a-select-element-of-chosen-plugin?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

when you clone your select, you also clone their IDs, but ID attirbute must be unique, also your chosen-select can be bounded to original select.

Answer (score 0):

In your link you are using id which is also get cloned and when you want to choose the second element first one is triggerd due to same id.