# How can I Clone Chosen Plugin

Tags: jquery, select, jquery-plugins, jquery-chosen

I wanted to use  http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/ witch jquery clone function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        var removeLink = ' <a class="remove" href="#" onclick="$(this).parent().slideUp(function(){ $(this).remove() }); return false">remove</a>';
        $('a.add').relCopy({ append: removeLink});
    });
</script>
<form method="post" action="">
    <div id="cloner">
    <p class="clone">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            jQuery(".chzn-select").data("placeholder","Search...").chosen();
        });
        </script>
        <select data-placeholder="Search..." name="actor_name[]" class="chzn-select" style="width:350px;" tabindex="2">
            <option value=""></option>
            <?php
                require_once '../engine/db.php';
                $rezultat_url = mysql_query("SELECT `id`, `actor_name` FROM `actors` ORDER BY `id` DESC");
                while($row=mysql_fetch_array($rezultat_url)){
                    $id = $row[id];
                    $aktor = $row[actor_name];
                    echo'<option value="'.$id.'">'.$actor.'</option>';
                }
            ?>
            </select>
        <input type="text" name="role_name[]" value="" />
        <input type="text" name="epi_count[]" value="" />
    </p>
    </div>
    <p><a href="#" class="add" rel=".clone">Add More</a></p>
    <script src="chosen.jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="prism.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../administrator/js/reCopy.js"></script>
</form>
```

This is my form clone'ing script:

```
/**
* jQuery-Plugin "relCopy"
*
* @version: 1.1.0, 25.02.2010
*
* @author: Andres Vidal
* code@andresvidal.com
* http://www.andresvidal.com
*
* Instructions: Call $(selector).relCopy(options) on an element with a jQuery type selector
* defined in the attribute "rel" tag. This defines the DOM element to copy.
* @example: $('a.copy').relCopy({limit: 5}); // <a href="example.com" class="copy" rel=".phone">Copy Phone</a>
*
* @param: string excludeSelector - A jQuery selector used to exclude an element and its children
* @param: integer limit - The number of allowed copies. Default: 0 is unlimited
* @param: string append - HTML to attach at the end of each copy. Default: remove link
* @param: string copyClass - A class to attach to each copy
* @param: boolean clearInputs - Option to clear each copies text input fields or textarea
*
*/

(function($) {
    $.fn.relCopy = function(options) {
        var settings = jQuery.extend({
            excludeSelector: ".exclude",
            emptySelector: ".empty",
            copyClass: "copy",
            append: '',
            clearInputs: true,
            limit: 0 // 0 = unlimited
        }, options);

        settings.limit = parseInt(settings.limit);
        // loop each element
        this.each(function() {

            // set click action
            $(this).click(function(){
            var rel = $(this).attr('rel'); // rel in jquery selector format
            var counter = $(rel).length;
            // stop limit
            if (settings.limit != 0 && counter >= settings.limit){
                return false;
            };

            var master = $(rel+":first");
            var parent = $(master).parent();
            var clone = $(master).clone(true).addClass(settings.copyClass+counter).append(settings.append);

            //Remove Elements with excludeSelector
            if (settings.excludeSelector){
                $(clone).find(settings.excludeSelector).remove();
            };

            //Empty Elements with emptySelector
            if (settings.emptySelector){
                $(clone).find(settings.emptySelector).empty();
            };

            // Increment Clone IDs
            if ( $(clone).attr('id') ){
                var newid = $(clone).attr('id') + (counter +1);
                $(clone).attr('id', newid);
            };

            // Increment Clone Children IDs
            $(clone).find('[id]').each(function(){
                var newid = $(this).attr('id') + (counter +1);
                $(this).attr('id', newid);
            });

            //Clear Inputs/Textarea
            if (settings.clearInputs){
                $(clone).find(':input').each(function(){
                var type = $(this).attr('type');
                    switch(type)
                    {
                        case "button":
                            break;
                        case "reset":
                            break;
                        case "submit":
                            break;
                        case "checkbox":
                            $(this).attr('checked', '');
                            break;
                        default:
                            $(this).val("");
                    }
                });
            };

            $(parent).find(rel+':last').after(clone);
            return false;

            }); // end click action

        }); //end each loop

        return this; // return to jQuery

    };
})(jQuery)
```

The problem is, that when i cloned Chosen plugin form, only the first one work and the all cloned ones shows dropdown from the firs one.

I found similar problem with some solution here --> [How to add Chosen Plugin to dynamically created / cloned CSS div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523395/how-to-add-chosen-plugin-to-dynamically-created-cloned-css-div)

But i have no idea how to fit it to my script. Can someone help adapt it to my script and can show me where should I copy it.

Comment: I'm guessing you didn't write "your script"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would add a condition to the clear inputs area to check for selects with the `.chz-select` class and perform the re-initialization as in the answer you linked:

**UPDATE**

Since you're cloning using the true parameter, you need to remove the data from the element before reinitializing it, also I found an issue with the chosen plugin not getting the calculated width of the element after adding `display:inline-block;` so I had to use a timeout to introduce a minimal delay before the reinitialization

```
//Clear Inputs/Textarea
if (settings.clearInputs){
    $(clone).find(':input').each(function(){
        var type = $(this).attr('type');
        switch(type)
        {
            case "button":
                   break;
            case "reset":
                   break;
            case "submit":
                   break;
            case "checkbox":
                   $(this).attr('checked', '');
                   break;
            default:
                   $(this).val("");
        }
        if ($(this).hasClass('chzn-select')) {
            $(this).next('.chzn-container').remove();
            $(this).css({display: "inline-block"}).removeClass("chzn-done");
            var that = $(this);
            setTimeout(function () {
                that.removeData('chosen').chosen();
            }, 0);
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: THX for your help.I set it up as you suggested, but now when I add a clone only first one still using Chosen plugin, rest become simple select forms.

Comment: what code do you use to initialize Chsoen on the original select?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery(".chzn-select").data("placeholder","Select something...").chosen();
  });
  </script>

Comment: Seems that I had a typo in my if statement, should be `hasClass('chzn-select')` did you correct that?

Comment: Yes. I did, but it's still the same.

Comment: Can you check your browser console (Ctrl+Shift+J) for any errors when you try to clone?

Comment: That's weird can you set up a fiddle with your markup and your clone script to make some tests? The code should work, I tested this `$('.side-by-side').first().clone().prependTo('body').find('.chzn-select').each(function(){$(this).next('.chzn-container').remove(); $(this).css('display','inline-block').removeClass('chzn-done').chosen();});` through console on the plugin page http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/ and it clones correctly

Comment: Thank you. It's works like a charm now. I hope it will be useful for others as well. Cheers!

Comment: @user2626377 Glad to help. Don't forget to mark this as your accepted answer by clicking on the green check mark to the left