# Custom plugin refer to wrong $(this) after the clone() JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to explain the problem in simple way.

I have a custom plugin which add click event to the text-fields which alert text-field value.

```
function()
{
            $(this).click(function()
            {
                alert($(this).val());
            });

}
```

I call the plugin like `$(document).customPlugin()`.

now if I do this:

```
var clonedTextField =  $("#text-one").clone(true);
$("#text-one").replaceWith(clonedTextField);
```

after clicking on cloned text-field I don't see the value of it, instead I see the value of text-field which I cloned from(the mother text-field).

I need the value of the current text-field(cloned text-field) not the mother text-field;

See the problem here:
http://jsfiddle.net/Z2hdm/5/

Comment: where are you setting the value for the cloned element?

Comment: Seems to work fine to me ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z2hdm/)). When I press the clone button, and then I change the value of the textfield, and finnaly I click on it, I can see the new value.

Comment: @NathanP. I have updated the question, it should not work like this.

Comment: @Praveen I set the value in UI or html.

Comment: @NathanP. I have added jsFiddle link, you can check it.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is **`plugs()`** method is not getting attached to the *cloned* elements.

> **`.clone( [withDataAndEvents ] )`**
>
> A Boolean indicating whether event handlers should be copied along
>   with the elements. As of jQuery 1.4, element data will be copied as
>   well.

AFIK, cloned elements will not include the 3rd party plugins.  So you neeed to re-attach it to the new cloned element like

```
$('input').replaceWith(cloned).plugs();
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/Z2hdm/6/)

Comment: this is not the answer, there is many plugins and many element which are loaded by ajax. I can not call all plugin for all of them after each ajax request.

Comment: @Eeliya `.plugs()` is not an event handler for the element so it cannot be copied to the new cloned elements.  You can check the documentation of `clone()` AFIK this is usually procedure.

Comment: @Eeliya on a quick search I found a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10523395/1671639) closely related to your problem.  where a 3rd party plugin cloning is discussed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have experience in writing jQuery plugin so I achieved it [this way](http://jsfiddle.net/Z2hdm/8/) hoping this is correct.

```
$.fn.plugs = function() {
    this.click(function() {
        alert($(this).val());
    }); 
}
```

Using this you don't lose the interest of using a plugin (I think), and you actually use an event handler which will be cloned using `.clone(true)`